# 2, 3, 9, 19, 36, 62, 92 - Which number is the odd one out?

Tags: odd-one-out

Which is the odd one out from the following:

2, 3, 9, 19, 36, 62, 92

Your options are:

1. **3**
2. **9**
3. **19**
4. **36**

I did not create this puzzle myself. It was shared by someone in my exam preparation group on Telegram.

Comment: Is this a puzzle that you created yourself? If not, please edit in where it came from - questions without attribution are subject to closure.

Comment: One can come up with practically any answer to questions like this. E.g. use Lagrange interpolation to construct a one-variable polynomial that takes these values except for the one you want to exclude at integers 1 through 6. To be able to provide a more helpful answer, it would be necessary to disclose the assumed background.

Comment: Do you have any more specific information on where this comes from? Is it part of some ongoing exam or competition?

Comment: I am just wondering is this supposed to be a sequence?

Comment: Yeah this is supposed to be part of logical reasoning sections. Very common in indian examinations. U can easily see these type of questions in exams for MBA like iift , nmat , snap ect.U can look for related questions for attribution on these kind of problems

Comment: Any chance the last number is supposed to be 99 instead of 92? That would allow for a very trivial sequence with a very obvious odd one out.

Answer (score 3):

> 19, because it has an even number of syllables.

Answer (score 3):

NEW ANSWER

> I think it is 19

Because

> It is the odd one out because it contains the only digit that is not shared by the other numbers in the list: which is 1. The rule is that all the digits of every number is shared by at least one digit from another number in the list.

Comment: Good observation, I like this answer

Answer (score 0):

Unsure because there are so many other valid answers supplied, but my guess is

> 3

Because

> It is the only number in the sequence where the sums of the factors is a
>  perfect square.

Answer (score -2):

> another shot in random direction

> ```
>  02 = 0000010
>  03 = 0000011
>  09 = 0001001
>  19 = 0010011
>  36 = 0100100
>  62 = 0111110
>  92 = 1011100
> ```

> 62 is the only one with binary symmetry in the range

Comment: Did you mean to spoiler the block quote with the list?

Comment: @TMK thanks ! I spoiled it meanwhile.

Answer (score -4):

The series is wrong and the wrong number is 3,it should be 4

2  4  9  19  36  62  99
+2 +5 +10 +17 +26 +37

The numbers which are being added in series are getting increased by odd no.
Ex 2+3 is 5
Then 5+5 is 10
Then 10+7 is 17
Then 17+9 is 26
Then 26+11 is 37

Comment: Beyond changing 3 to 4, you've changed the last number from 92 to 99.

Comment: You cannot be certain that the author of the puzzle made a mistake, so this answer is not valid. If you believe the author made a mistake, you can ask them in the comments (once you have enough reputation).

Comment: I've the ques in my ssc book and it's 99, please ask him to recheck the ques again,if u can provide ur Gmail I'd i can send u the question

Comment: Maybe the puzzle in your book is *a different puzzle*